# i want alice to run any command as root, but can not run commands as any other user

Tags: linux, macos, unix, security, sudo

Say I have 2 users - 'alice' and 'bob' and want to allow 'alice' to run any command as root, but not run commands as 'bob' or any other user, am I able to do this, and if so how ?

consider this example that allows james to run any command as alice

james ALL=(alice) ALL

or this example that allows fred to run the ls command as root

fred ALL=(root) /bin/ls

I suspect it has something to do with modifications to /etc/sudoers, along the lines of

```
alice ALL=(root)  ALL ?
```

Comment: If you're giving `alice` the ability to run any command as `root`, you are giving her _complete_, _total_ control over the computer. If you don't trust her with the ability to run commands as another user, you should not give her `root`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? or trying to prevent? If you give alice root, she can make any file (as root) read/write any file (as root) change the owners... the only thing they can't do is get root perms on NFS volumes (unless they configured them for this). You're not blocking anything.

Comment: It sounds like you either need [better access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), or the use of sandbox-style program execution (e.g. [Docker](http://docker.io/)).  There's no good reason to do this as stated...

Comment: Simple example of how your proposed line fails: `sudo su bob`. Bam. Alice now has a shell as bob. Disallow su? `cp /bin/sh ~/bobsh`; `sudo chown bob:users bobsh`; `sudo chmod 4055 bobsh`. Bam. You now have a copy of the in your home directory that always runs as bob. Disallow those? Write a C program that calls `setuid` with bob's uid and then `exec`s a shell. Compile it, run as root. You now are in a shell as bob. There are _so many_ ways to do it that you pretty much need a whitelist-based system.

Answer (score 5):

Once you're root, you can become any other user.

If you can limit alice to a restricted set of approved commands, you **may** be able to keep her from becoming another user, but then each command she runs as root needs to be checked to see if they have leaks that let her use a non-approved program. But this is very complex, and may not be feasible.

Comment: there has to be a easier way it is just in the /etc/sudoers

Comment: @whatsup1234 root can control anything, including becoming any other user. You just gave alice ALL perms, including a root shell, which lets her become any user.

Comment: There is no easier way. `root` can do _anything_ on the system. Anything. For example, as `root`, alice could make a copy of `bash`, `chown` it to `bob:users`, and set the setuid bit on it. That would mean that any user running it runs it as `bob`. Alternatively (and more easily), `alice` could just run `su bob` and it _will work_. All `sudoers` lets you do is restrict `alice` to certain _commands_, but each of those commands runs with full `root` privileges, and so any issue in any of those commands lets `alice` authenticate as `bob`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Linux capabilities would let you launch a process without the ability to change user, even if root.  `setcap` may do what you need, or you may want to look into SELinux.  However, there needs to be more development work done in this area, it seems.  [Look at this Stack Overflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user)

Comment: from that post, it seems that setcap sets on a per executable basis. But, OQ set sudo rights to do anything, so you'd need to do the impossible - block all possible paths.